# JQuery. Why can't I insert an html img tag in a textarea?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, textarea

TextArea looks like:

```
<textarea id="MessageContent" name="MessageContent"></textarea>
```

JQuery looks like:

```
 $("#insert").live("click", function () {
             var t = "<img width='" + result.width + "' height='" + result.height + "' alt='" + result.descr + "' src='/Images/" + result.message + "' />";
             $("#MessageContent").html($("#MessageContent").html() + t);
             $("#MessageContent").focus();

             $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("fast");
             $("#popupContact").fadeOut("fast");
         });      //live
```

I can insert simple text, but can't insert any HTML tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) here instead of [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to set a `<textarea>`'s value (otherwise the value isn't encoded, or used properly), like this:

```
$("#insert").live("click", function () {
  var t = "<img width='" + result.width + "' height='" + result.height + "' alt='" + result.descr + "' src='/Images/" + result.message + "' />";
  $("#MessageContent").val($("#MessageContent").val() + t);
  $("#MessageContent").focus();

  $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("fast");
  $("#popupContact").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

You can also shorten it a bit [by passing a function to `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2), like this:

```
$("#insert").live("click", function () {
  $("#MessageContent").val(function(i, val) {
     return val + "<img width='" + result.width + "' height='" + result.height + "' alt='" + result.descr + "' src='/Images/" + result.message + "' />";
   }).focus(); 
  $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("fast");
  $("#popupContact").fadeOut("fast");
});
```